# Using Mojo::DOM to extract untagged text after heading

Tags: perl, mojo-dom

I'm trying to extract some text without tags from a HTML file using Mojo::DOM (I'm new at this). In particular, the description text after the H2 heading (there are other headings in the file).

```
<h2>Description</h2>This text is the description<div class="footer">[<a href="/contrib/rev/1597/2795/">Edit description</a>
```

I've been able to find the heading, but don't know how to access the text after is, since I have not tag to jump to...

```
my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new( $htmlfile );
my $desc = $dom
    ->find('h2')
    ->grep(sub { $_->all_text =~ /Description/ })
    ->first;
```

Can anyone recommend to me a way how to grab the "This text is the description" string?

Comment: could you post a bit more HTML, like the parent elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One can go through *all* nodes, what also catches those which aren't inside an HTML element (tag). Then use the fact that you need the node that follows the `h2` tag.

More precisely, it follows the text-node which is the child of the (identifiable) `h2` tag-node.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use Mojo::DOM;

my $html = q(<h2>Description</h2> This text is the description <p>More...</p>);

my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new($html);

my $is_next = 0;

foreach my $node ($dom->descendant_nodes->each) { 
    my $par = $node->parent;
    if ($node->type eq 'text' and $par->type eq 'tag' and $par->tag eq 'h2') { 
        $is_next = 1;
    }   
    elsif ($is_next) {
        say $node;       #-->   This text is the description
        $is_next = 0;
    }   
}
```

More criteria for exactly which `h2` nodes are of interest can be added (unless it's really all such nodes), by interrogating either the previous text-node (text of the `h2` tag) or its parent (the tag).

The node itself should likely be checked as well, for example to see whether it's indeed just loose text and not actually a next tag.

I've tested with far more complex HTML; the above is a near-minimal testable markup.

---

In this simple example just `$dom->text` catches the needed text. However, that won't be the case in more complex fragments where the sought text doesn't come after the very first element.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code, I have just added a parent element:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Mojo::DOM;


my $html = q{<div class="container"><h2>Description</h2>This text is the description<div class="footer">[<a href="/contrib/rev/1597/2795/">Edit description</a>
</div></div>};

my $dom = Mojo::DOM->new($html);

print $dom->at('div.container')->text();
```

Alternatively, using your HTML snippet, the following can be done:

```
print $dom->text();
```